# How to properly specify argument type accepting dictionary values?

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting, python-typing

Here are a couple of functions:

```py
from typing import Sequence

def avg(vals: Sequence[float]):
    return sum(val for val in vals) / len(vals)

def foo():
    the_dict = {'a': 1., 'b': 2.}
    return avg(the_dict.values())
```

PyCharm 2022.3 warns about `the_dict.values()` in the last line:

> Expected type 'Sequence[float]', got _dict_values[float, str] instead

But those values can be iterated across and have their length taken.

I tried

```
from typing import Sequence, Union

def avg(vals: Union[Sequence[float], _dict_values]):
    ...
```

which seems insane, but that also didn't work.

Suggestions?

I can turn off the typing for that argument, but I am curious what the right annotation is.

Comment: Sequence also requires `__getitem__` access. Collection probably fits best here

Comment: Also, you can side-step the issue by using `fmean` or `mean` from the `statistics` module.

Answer (score 3):

`_dict_values` is not a `Sequence` (it's closer to an `Iterator`). Lucky `avg` doesn't require everything `Sequence` ensures. You only need `Iterable[float]` for `sum` and `Sized` for `len()`.

```py
from collections.abc import Iterable, Sized
from typing import Protocol


class SupportsFloatMean(Iterable[float], Sized, Protocol):
    ...


def avg(vals: SupportsFloatMean):
    return sum(val for val in vals) / len(vals)
```

Comment: Just a minor remark: You should use the abstract base classes from `collections.abc` instead of `typing`. The latter are deprecated since `3.9` (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#abstract-base-classes)). Also technically, the `for`-loop requires the `Iterable` in this case and the resulting generator expression is passed to `sum`, but that is nitpicking.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the broadest possible type compatible with your `avg` function, you'll just need one that supports the `Iterable` protocol (used in the `for`-loop) and the `Sized` protocol (used by the `len` function). Unfortunately, none of those two inherits from the other, as you can see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes).

Thus, an intersection of the two is what you'll need to create. This is made possible (in this case) with [`typing.Protocol`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol) as mentioned here in [PEP 544](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/#unions-and-intersections-of-protocols) and as used beautifully in [@PeterSutton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74921239/19770795).

If you want to be a bit less verbose, without the need for a custom protocol, and *almost* just as broad, you can simply use the [`Collection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Collection) ABC. It inherits from `Iterable` and `Sized` as well as `Container`. The latter defines the `__contains__` method, meaning you can do `in`-checks with it, which you technically do not need in your `avg` function.

The `Collection` is obviously still a superclass of `ValuesView`, as you can see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes), so you'll have no trouble calling `avg` with your `dict.values`.

```py
from collections.abc import Collection


def avg(vals: Collection[float]) -> float:
    return sum(val for val in vals) / len(vals)


def foo() -> float:
    the_dict = {'a': 1., 'b': 2.}
    return avg(the_dict.values())
```

Also, don't forget your return type annotations. ;-)